# Select unique rows with distinct column

Tags: sql-server, select

I want to select rows that have a distinct `d` (and `P`, `dw`), see the example table below:

```
Bezeichnung  Norm       d   P    dw
--------------------------------------
M14 x 130   ISO 4014    14  2    19,15
M14 x 140   ISO 4014    14  2    19,15
M18 x 70    ISO 4014    18  2,5  24,85
M18 x 80    ISO 4014    18  2,5  24,85
M22 x 220   ISO 4014    22  2,5  31,35
M22 x 90    ISO 4014    22  2,5  31,35
M36 x 340   ISO 4014    36  4    51,11
M36 x 140   ISO 4014    36  4    51,11
M20 x 100   ISO 4014    20  2,5  27,7
M20 x 110   ISO 4014    20  2,5  27,7
```

The desired result would be:

```
Bezeichnung  Norm       d   P    dw
--------------------------------------
M14 x 130   ISO 4014    14  2    19,15
M18 x 70    ISO 4014    18  2,5  24,85
M22 x 220   ISO 4014    22  2,5  31,35
M36 x 340   ISO 4014    36  4    51,11
M20 x 100   ISO 4014    20  2,5  27,7
```

Where I don't care which `Bezeichnung` column value is returned. What would be the required SQL?

Comment: Something like this: select distinct Bezeichnung, Norm, d, P, dw from table  - but it doesn't work

Comment: I think you can use group by clause . If you can share create table scrit I can help you to write sql query

Answer (score 2):

You need to `GROUP BY` on the values you want to group by and then use an aggregate function on the other columns, such as `MIN` or `MAX`

```
SELECT MAX(Bezeichnung)
      ,MAX(Norm)
      ,d
      ,P
      ,dw
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY d, P, dw
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you need the Bezeichnung and Norm columns to come from the same row. In your sample data it doesn't matter because all the Norm values are the same, but if you can have different Norm values would it matter if you had a Bezeichnung value from one row and a Norm value from a different row? If you don't care at all what these columns contain then you could completely ignore them and just:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d, P, dw FROM myTable
```

If you do want to see a Bezeichnung value and a Norm value but it doesn't matter if these values are from the same row then the answer from @dan-field will do the trick.

If you want to get Bezeichnung and Norm values that always come from the same row then you need:

```
;with Results as
    (select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By d, P, dw) rownum, *
    from myTable)
select Bezeichnung, Norm, d, P, dw from Results where rownum = 1
```